# PIPENV hangs at install from existing pipfile.lock on Raspberry pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pipenv

Python beginner here who is working on a small portfolio tracking project. I was using PIPENV so far to manage my VENV which work AWESOME so far. Loved it much more than PIP and VENV seperately.

However today I encountered a problem: I was coding on my Laptop (Linux Mint) inside a PIPENV based on Python 3.6.5. and was installing packages through PIPENV.

Lock: https://github.com/rstoermer/traq/blob/master/Pipfile.lock
Pipfile: https://github.com/rstoermer/traq/blob/master/Pipfile

Through GIT I cloned this to my Raspberry Pi and did a "pipenv install --Python 3.6". This began to hang. Therefore I tried a few things, including:

- Reinstalling PIPENV using PIP
- Installing PIPENV with Python 3.5
- Installing PIPENV without Pipfiles and installing packages manually --> pipenv install pandas did hang as well

My current approach: I removed all VENVS created by PIPENV and did a new "pipenv install --python 3.6" with the lockfile mentioned above. The install hangs some time at package 15/68, afterwards I get a "An error occured while installing XXX, Will try again". Then it takes a really long time again at 31/68 and finally hangs at 47/68 for now 15 minutes. Not sure if anything will happen from now on:

[image]

Comment: After 17 more minutes stuck at package 47 I canceled the install...

Comment: Changed back to VENV...

Comment: Having a similar problem right now, where after a while pipenv reported that the package hash sums did not match those in the requirements file. Seems like on Raspberry PIs, you get slightly different versions of some packages. I could successfully install the project ignoring the locked version hashes with `pipenv install --skip-lock`.